# Javascript handle over password type inputs

Tags: javascript, security, dom, input, passwords

Why Javascript can to retrieve the value data from password type inputs? Any browser extension could to handle it.

Comment: Exact. That's why most browsers tend to have permission management and inform you if extensions want to access or manipulate DOM elements.

Comment: I think originally no one thought about extensions or JavaScript which doesn't come from the website's author.

Comment: Completely off-topic for stack overflow. Anyhow, I keep cleaning malicious extensions from people's browsers, but would the alternative make sense? At some point the user has to turn on their brain.

Comment: Where should I ask that? It's a honest question. That's scares me.